# How to search case-insensitive using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I just wanna know how to search in case-insensitive.

For example I type `Superman` and I click the search button. I want to display results *case-insensitive* like `superman`, `SuPeRmAN` and etc.

I am using JSP and jQuery. Thanks in advance! :)

```
function searchGroupPackage() {
    if ($('#detailVal').val() !== "") {
       $('#searchHeaderForm').attr("action", "search_user.html");
       $('#searchHeaderForm').attr("method", "POST");
       $('#searchHeaderForm').submit();
    } else {
        $('#detailVal').css({
            'border': 'solid 1px violet'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? What elements are you attempting to search? We need some context in order to help.

Comment: How can I post my code here? Without destroying the structure of it. Sorry I am new here.

Comment: Put it in the original post, and put 1 empty line between the code and the other paragraphs. Then, indent each line of your code by 4 spaces.

Comment: @ShamSUP

function searchGroupPackage() {

    if ($('#detailVal').val() !== "") {

        $('#searchHeaderForm').attr("action", "search_user.html");

        $('#searchHeaderForm').attr("method", "POST");

        $('#searchHeaderForm').submit();

    } else {
        
        $('#detailVal').css({

                        'border': 'solid 1px violet'

                    });

                }

            }

Comment: I don't see where searching without case sensitivity applies to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
search = your_string_to_be_found_in_text.toLowerCase();

whole_string.toLowerCase().search(search);
```

(convert both to lowercase and search)